# Is there a way to find the differing value(s) in a data frame column and str list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare and have returned the difference between a data frame column and a list. See below for further explanation.

flights_df['ORIGINSTATENAME'] = ['New York', 'California', 'Texas', 'Hawaii', 'Massachusetts', 'Fakestate', 'Washington', 'Florida', 'North Carolina', 'Illinois']

states = ['New York', 'California', 'Texas', 'Hawaii', 'Massachusetts', 'Washington', 'Florida', 'North Carolina', 'Illinois']

Is there a way to compare these two and have returned the value that doesn't exist in the other.

Expected output:
{'Fakestate'}

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.contains` along with a whitelist regex alternation of states.

```py
states = ['New York', 'California', 'Texas', 'Hawaii', 'Massachusetts', 'Washington', 'Florida', 'North Carolina', 'Illinois']
regex = r'\b(?:' + r'|'.join(states) + r')\b'
flights_df["missing"] = flights_df.loc[flights_df['ORIGINSTATENAME'].str.contains(regex)]
```